# Xcode 5 — wrong interface on a device with iOS7

Tags: interface-builder, ios7

My setting for the project:

- Deployment target: iOS6.1
- Base SDK: 7.0
- IB Document: Opens in 5.0

When I run app in simulator(7.0) I see almost what I expect (I don't understand why barbuttons don't use color tint — on previous screen it shows blue):
[image]

But if app is running on a device (also 7.0),
Then I see:
[image]
As you can see this is some kind of iOS6 UI, but tableview goes under the navbar, which became transparent.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Jeebus - WWCD13 videos - iOS transition guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior of `tintColor` for bars has changed on iOS 7.0, please check the image below:

[image]

So now to change the tint color for your bar buttons you need to use `tintColor` which is the color for the interactive elements within a navigation bar including button images and titles.

While `barTintColor` is the background color of the `UINavigationBar`.

So basically
For buttons and title:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

For bar tint:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

For the tableVIew under the navBar part, set `navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Comment: I checked tint for that controller, and it was default in IB (blue). Setting it programmatically did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Autolayout in IB, and now it uses iOS7 on a device too.
Upd.: After some time it start show strange design again. It gone only after I set iOS7 as base and deployment SDK.